# Responsive images inline

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to place 2 images in one line but keep them responsive with bootstrap.

I've tried using

```
<img src="..." class="float-left" alt="...">
<img src="..." class="float-right" alt="...">
```

and keep them responsive with

```
<img src="..." class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
```

but when I'm trying to mix these, it doesn't work like this:

```
<img src="..." class="img-fluid float-left"
<img src="..." class="img-fluid float-right"
```

```
<div class="allatok">
<img class="float-left" src="img/portfolio/labrador.png" alt="" style="height: 400px;">
<div class="papagaj">
<img class="float-right" src="img/portfolio/labrador.png" alt="" style="height: 400px;">
</div>
</div>
```

The problem is, these are not responsive at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just putting the 2 images inside a div with class `d-flex`, but each image needs to wrapped in a `div` as well.

The class `img-fluid` is giving `max-width: 100%` to the images so unless you wrap them in an additional div they are going wider than you want.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="imgwrap d-flex">
  <div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1025/400" class="img-fluid" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/400" class="img-fluid" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works but Ive got 2 problems with it. I cant align them in the center with `<div class="text-center">` and when i resize the site, the pictures will be smaller, but not blocking inline. I'd like to see them under each other.

Comment: That’s one of the advantages of flexbox, use a media query at the break point you want and in that query add flex-direction:column; to the wrapper div, will stack the items vertically!